# Crashlytics ndk fails to load

Tags: crashlytics, crashlytics-android

stepping into crashlytics_init() it is able to do the dlopen() and dlsym() calls to valid addresses. But the sym_ini() call returns null.

not sure how do debug why its not loading? there is nothing logged to logcat.

```
Crashlytics crashlyticsKit = new Crashlytics.Builder()
            .core(new CrashlyticsCore.Builder().disabled(BuildConfig.DEBUG).build())
            .build();
Fabric.with(this, crashlyticsKit,new CrashlyticsNdk());
```

Comment: Mike from Fabric here. Can you share your Fabric init code?

Comment: i have the same problem. dlopen and dlsym succeed but sym_ini fails.