# Cannot initialize Crashlytics NDK

Tags: crashlytics, crashlytics-android

I got a problem in initalizing Crashlytics for Android. The Java part works correctly but i cannot make NDK part to work because crashlytics_init() return a null value;

My project/build.gradle

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        google()
        maven {
            url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public'
        }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.0'
        classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.24.4'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.1.0'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        google()

        maven {
            url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public'
        }

    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

app/build.gradle containing

```
compileSdkVersion 26

android {

    defaultConfig {
        ...
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 22
        ...
    }

    ...
}

crashlytics {
    enableNdk true
    manifestPath 'C:\\full\\path\\to\\manifest\\AndroidManifest.xml'
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crash:11.6.0'
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')

    compile('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.7.1@aar') {
        transitive = true
    }
    compile('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics-ndk:1.1.6@aar') {
        transitive = true;
    }

    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:11.6.0'

    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:26.1.0'
    compile 'org.apache.commons:commons-compress:1.12'
    compile 'org.tukaani:xz:1.5'
}
```

main activity code

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    jniCrashlyticsInit();

    ...
}
```

and the native content of jniCrashlyticsInit()

```
void Java_com_my_app_MainActivity_jniCrashlyticsInit(JNIEnv *env,
                                                     jobject thiz)
{
    crashlytics = crashlytics_init();

    if (crashlytics == NULL)
        log("CRASHLYTICS NULL");
    else
        log("CRASHLYTICS NON NULL");
}
```

As you imagine, "CRASHLYTICS NULL" is logged and it cannot initialize all the stuff.
I've put logs also inside `crashlytics.h` and it happens to fail on this line (returning a null value)

```
__crashlytics_unspecified_t* ctx = ((__crashlytics_initialize_t) sym_ini)();
```

Since i got no further infos, i really don't know how to proceed.
Ideas?

Some info more:
I use Android studio 3.0.0, and the NDK libraries are compiled manually with the following command

```
/cygdrive/c/Android/ndk-r15c/ndk-build.cmd NDK_DEBUG=0 APP_BUILD_SCRIPT=./Android.mk NDK_PROJECT_PATH=. APP_PLATFORM=android-19
```

**** Update November 20th ****

As suggested by Todd Burner, I switched from *"compile"* to *"implementation"* on `build.gradle` from

```
compile('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.7.1@aar') {
    transitive = true
}
compile('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics-ndk:1.1.6@aar') {
    transitive = true;
}
```

to

```
implementation('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.7.1@aar') {
    transitive = true
}
implementation('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics-ndk:1.1.6@aar') {
    transitive = true;
}
```

then i ran

```
./gradlew assemble --refresh-dependencies
```

Unfortunally, `crashlytics_init()` still returns NULL

Comment: Thanks for reaching out. We don't yet officially support AS 3 and that could explain this. Can you let me know if you have run into any issues with AS 2.x.x. Was this project migrated or was it setup as a new project in AS 3? Thanks!

Comment: Thank you for reply! Project is 2 years old and I moved to AS 3 last week but i tried to use Crashlytics yesterday for the first time. Therefore i got no idea if it worked on AS 2. Sorry :( BTW, java crashes are perfectly detected and gathered.

Comment: Can you try switching compile to implementation and running ./gradlew assemble --refresh-dependencies Thanks!

Comment: Mr Burner, i did what you've suggested (pls check the updated question). No luck X(

Comment: Maybe you forgot to initialize CrashlyticsNdk on Java side? See it here, it helped me: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47211657/crashlytics-ndk-fails-to-load

P.S. Crashlytics NDK documentation is bad: it lacks a lot of information and examples...

Answer (score 0):

I struggled days with this same issue. In my case I would blame partly the not-so-very-thorough documentation in the Fabric website and partly the lack of my reading comprehension.

I cannot be sure if you experience just the same thing, but my problem was that I tried to load Crashlytics NDK twice.

If you do the initialization from java like this:

```
Fabric.with(this, new Crashlytics(), new CrashlyticsNdk());
```

the native Crashlytics is automatically loaded and **you don't need to initialize Crashlytics from C++**. If you step into the decompiled Crashlytics .class files starting from `CrashlyticsNdk.class` you can see that `JniNativeApi.class` already calls `System.loadLibrary("crashlytics")`.

In fact, if you still try to initialize Crashlytics from native side after that, the line

```
__crashlytics_unspecified_t* ctx = ((__crashlytics_initialize_t) sym_ini)();
```

will return NULL because the library has been already loaded.

What confused me is that the [Official Fabric documentation](https://docs.fabric.io/android/crashlytics/ndk.html) doesn't say with bright red flashing letters that if you call `new CrashlyticsNdk()` from Java, you shouldn't try to load native Crashlytics from C++. To be fair, the documentation does say the following: *In the process of initialization via Fabric.with(), the NDK Kit uses System.loadLibrary to load libcrashlytics.* But it's a single line right before the Native API explanation starts and is easily overlooked.

Comment: I tried this and sym_ini still returns NULL. The documentation says that when crashlytics_init is called, the library has already been loaded by new CrashlyticsNdk().  I think this is how it's supposed to work.

Comment: If sym_ini returns NULL, then you didn't really try it, because my solution was not to call crashlytics_init() at all. Just load the library from java side with new CrashlyticsNdk() and do nothing in C++ side. Then cause a test crash in C++ side. At least in my project I can see the native crash dump in Fabric.

Comment: My objective was to be able to annotate additional information in the C crash reports. The documentation states that this is possible through the  crashlytics_context_t::log method but you need a crashlytics context in order to call that.  I can't get a crashlytics context unless I call crashlytics_init().