# Could we get info from `new CrashlyticsNdk()` to know OK or not in java code?

Tags: crashlytics, crashlytics-android

I have the same issue like
[Cannot initialize Crashlytics NDK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47285017/cannot-initialize-crashlytics-ndk) and
[Crashlytics ndk fails to load](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47211657/crashlytics-ndk-fails-to-load) .

Could we get info from `new CrashlyticsNdk()` to know OK or not in java code?

the project https://github.com/mapsme/omim uses crashlytics:

https://github.com/mapsme/omim/blob/d002e4d647020efd6452734b88f4eb64515687e0/android/src/com/mapswithme/maps/MwmApplication.java

```
public void initCrashlytics()
{
    ...

    Fabric.with(this, new Crashlytics(), new CrashlyticsNdk());

    nativeInitCrashlytics();

    mCrashlyticsInitialized = true;
}
```

in cpp, the code is same as we used:

https://github.com/mapsme/omim/blob/55278deba6db6830d5215fd246c42e7a9ebbc4d4/android/jni/com/mapswithme/maps/MwmApplication.cpp

but I can not find any way to know.

Comment: Can you clarify the type of info you're looking to get?

Comment: There is no error info/log from `crashlytics_init()` returning null, maybe something wrong in `Fabric.with(this, new Crashlytics(), new CrashlyticsNdk())`. Is there some log or other info to know which step has a problem?