# Crashlytics Android ndk doesn't initialize

Tags: crashlytics, crashlytics-android

From my C code in the Android NDK app, I'm trying to initialize Crashlytics but it's returning NULL.

```
LOGW ("Initializing Crashlytics");
crashlyticsContext = crashlytics_init();
LOGI ("crashlyticsContext: %lx", (uint32_t) crashlyticsContext);
```

In the logcat log, I'm getting a Permission Denial log:

```
W/SimTalk: Initializing Crashlytics
W/ActivityManager: Permission Denial: getCurrentUser() from pid=18043, uid=10079 requires android.permission.INTERACT_ACROSS_USERS
I/SimTalk: crashlyticsContext: 0
```

My build.gradle file includes the compile line for the NDK:

```
compile('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics-ndk:2.0.2@aar') {
    transitive = true
}
```

and the crashlytics section

```
crashlytics {
    enableNdk true
}
```

and my AndroidManifest.xml file does contain my metadata:

```
<meta-data
    android:name="io.fabric.ApiKey"
    android:value="............omitted.............." />
```

Do you have any idea why my crashlytics_init() isn't working?

**Update:**
I've determined that the dlopen() call in crashlytics_init() is returning NULL. The libcrashlytics.so file is included in the APK along with the other libs.  It's still not loading, though.

Comment: The log is quite clear. `requires android.permission.INTERACT_ACROSS_USERS` Do you have that permission in your manifest file?

Comment: I tried it and it didn't work.  I'm starting to suspect that it's a random log that happens on my tablet even when I'm not running my app.

Comment: After more debugging, I've found that the libcrashlytics.so library couldn't be found unless I provided the full path to the library.  After doing that, the library loaded fine but sym_ini returns NULL.  This is the same problem as https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47211657/crashlytics-ndk-fails-to-load